# Remove Email from AWS SES Suppression List

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I know we need to raise a request in SES console to remove an email from the suppression list.
Are there different ways to remove previously bounced emails in bulk from the suppression list without waiting for 14 days?

Our application administrator would not have direct AWS console access where he/she can raise a request. Even if they have access,  it is tedious to remove multiple emails by placing individual removal requests.

What are the options/alternatives that are available?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response from AWS Forum at this thread:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=530774

A programmatic way to remove an email from AWS SES suppression list is not available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of suppression lists -

1. Account level suppression list (You need AWS CLI)

Here is the documentation about removing email(s) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-suppression-list.html

2. Global suppression list

Documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-global-suppression-list.html

Answer (score 0):

- Generate Access/Secret keys against aws iam user
- Configure aws  cli using `aws configure`
- Replace the region name with your own in the bash script
- Finally execute the bash script. Thanks me later!

  #!/bin/bash

  ```
   # AWS SES Suppression List Management Script

   # AWS CLI command to list all email addresses in the suppression list
   suppression_list=$(aws sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations --region <your-region>)

   # Extracting email addresses from the suppression list
   email_addresses=$(echo $suppression_list | jq -r '.SuppressedDestinationSummaries[].EmailAddress')

   # Loop through each email address and remove it from the suppression list
   for email in $email_addresses; do
     echo "Removing $email from the suppression list..."
     aws sesv2 delete-suppressed-destination --region <your-region> --email-address $email
   done

   echo "All email addresses removed from the suppression list."
  ```